# Initialization: Function vs. literal

Tags: c, initialization, pthreads, mutex

I notice that, in libraries like libpthread, there will be structures which can be allocated in one of two ways.  For example, a `pthread_mutex_t` can be initialized statically via

```c
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

or dynamically via

```c
pthread_mutex_init(&lock);
```

However, unless I'm missing something, the `pthread_mutex_init` function is superfluous.  That is, couldn't I just do

```
lock = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

?

Comment: `pthread_mutex_init` takes more parameters and that makes the difference.

Comment: ^^^^ reason the `pthread_mutex_init(&lock);` shown wouldn't compile, so there's that. Second, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is intended to function correctly in the context of what the name implies: *initialization*. That you must hard-cast whatever/however it is defined to your desired type for your code to even compile where you're trying to use it in an assignment context, not initialization, is a screaming flag you shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration for [`pthread_mutex_init()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) is:

> ```
> int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
>                        const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
> ```

So you can provide selected attributes to the initializer via the function call which you cannot via an assignment using `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

However, if you're happy with the default attributes, there's no obvious reason why you couldn't use the 'compound literal' assignment notation.

Note that it would be unwise to 'destroy' a previously used mutex by an assignment reinitializing it. Always use the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` function to destroy a mutex.  And if you're using a local variable for the mutex, make sure it is always destroyed before the variable goes out of scope.  And don't destroy a mutex while it is in use.  The POSIX page referenced above covers many of these points.

Answer (score 2):

> That is, couldn't I just do
>
> ```
> lock = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
> ```
>
> ?

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` expands to an initializer suitable for an object of type `pthread_mutex_t`, declared at file scope.  This must take the form of either a brace-enclosed initializer list or a constant of a type compatible with `pthread_mutex_t`.

- **if it is a brace-enclosed initializer list** then prefixing it with `(pthread_mutex_t)` produces a compound literal of type `pthread_mutex_t`.  Provided that that is not an array type and that it does not directly or indirectly contain any `const` members, the C language permits such an assignment.
- **if it is a constant of a type compatible with `pthread_mutex_t`** then prefixing it with `(pthread_mutex_t)` forms a typecast expression, which the C language allows only if `pthread_mutex_t` is a void or scalar type.  A reasonably likely alternative in this category would be that `pthread_mutex_t` is a structure type and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` expands to a compound literal, and the cast would violate a language constraint in this case.

From a C-language perspective, then, it is not safe to assume that you can perform such an assignment.

From a POSIX perspective, the spec does not specify the form of the expansion of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, and does not designate it suitable for the use you describe.  POSIX-conforming C implementations are therefore free to implement it with any kind of built-in or special-casing they wish, and that is not required to correctly handle any case other than its use as an initializer.

From both those angles, no, it is not safe to do as you describe.

Additionally, as other answers have observed, the initializer macro is suitable only for the case where you are satisfied with the default mutex attributes.  If you want non-default attributes, such as for a robust or process-shared mutex, then you must use `pthread_mutex_init()` to get them.  Notwithstanding all the foregoing, then, no, `pthread_mutex_init()` is not superfluous.

Comment: Why would it be illegal if `pthread_mutex_t` was a structure type and the macro expanded to a compound literal?

Comment: As I already said, @DanielWalker, because C allows only void and scalar types as operands of cast operators.  Structure types are neither, and if `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` expands to a compound literal of a structure type then in the expansion of your `lock = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, the right-hand side of the assignment contains a cast of a structure type.

Comment: Hm, that's strange.  I use that type of cast (`(some_struct_t){0}`) all the time.

Comment: @DanielWalker, that is not a cast.  That whole thing, including the `(some_struct_t)`, is a compound literal.

Comment: So, what would be an example of an illegal cast?

Comment: @DanielWalker, `some_struct_t s1 = { 0 }; some_struct_t s2 = (some_struct_t) s1;`.  Or, closer to the case in question, `some_struct_t s3 = (some_struct_t) (some_struct_t) { 0 };`.

Comment: Ahhh, okay.  Got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken the function is declared like

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
    const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
```

that is it has two parameters.

The function can be called for already existent mutex and the user can specify any acceptable attributes apart from default mutex attributes.

As for the macro `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` then according to the description

> In cases where default mutex attributes are appropriate, the macro
> PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize mutexes that are
> statically allocated. The effect is equivalent to dynamic
> initialization by a call to pthread_mutex_init() with parameter attr
> specified as NULL, **except that no error checks are performed**.

Comment: Note that POSIX says _"Attempting to initialize an already initialized mutex results in undefined behavior"._